# Share Nvim configure with other user?

Tags: vim

Im currently using NeoVim and appearently it can only run with root privilege.

When Im using a normal user and try `nvim`, it show the error :

```
rror detected while processing /home/tuananh/.config/nvim/vim-plug/plugins.vim:
line    9:
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command:     Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
line   14:
E492: Not an editor command:     Plug 'scrooloose/NERDTree'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command:     Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
line   17:
E492: Not an editor command:     Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
line   19:
E117: Unknown function: plug#end
Error detected while processing /home/tuananh/.config/nvim/themes/gruvbox.vim:
line    4:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'gruvbox'
E886: System error while opening ShaDa file /home/tuananh/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada for reading: permission denied
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to install vim plug for that user too. See: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#installation . Then it's likely you'll need to run `:PlugInstall` to install the plugins for that user too.

Comment: Tks for answer :D